# Avoid throwing expectation_failure when expectation parser fails

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

How to avoid throwing an exception, when expectation parser fails?

I have a rule `"function" > (!x3::lexeme[keyword >> !(x3::alnum | '_')] >> symbol) > ('(' > -lvalue_list > ')') > statements > "end"` to parse code like:

```
function a() return one end
```

`keyword`s is (`zero`, `one`, `function`, `return`, `end` etc).

If I feed the parser with `function one() return zero end` code, then in function `expect_directive::parse` exception thrown from here:

```
if (!r)
{
    boost::throw_exception(
        expectation_failure<Iterator>(
        first, what(this->subject)));
}
```

When it happens, I got **The program has unexpectedly finished.** or **Aborted (core dumped)** (depending on terminal used).

When debugging the code **gdb** automatically breaks on closing brace '}' in `boost::throw_exception` function with message:

```
The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the Operating System.

Signal name : 
SIGABRT
Signal meaning : 
Aborted
```

When stepping through mentioned function step by step it is seen, that `throw enable_current_exception(enable_error_info(e));` line is the last line executed before signal emitting. Why there is no stack unwinding for exception handler searching? Why abort instantly raised (looks like `boost::throw_exception` have `noexcept` specifier)?

I have embraced into `try { ... } catch (x3::expectation_failure< input_iterator_type > const & ef) { ... }` `x3::phrase_parse` function call. `x3::expectation_failure< input_iterator_type >` is exactly the expection thrown from `boost::throw_exception`. All it does not matter.

Is there a way to completely avoid `x3::expectation_failure` exception in *Boost.Spirit X3*, but still interrupt parsing of code overall and make `x3::phrase_parse` to return `false` on expectation failure?

**My suspicions are next:**

Due to conventional return value of `parse()` member function of all parsers (as concept in *X3*) is `bool`, I suspect there are only two ways to report about failure: exception xor return code (which can be only `true` or `false`, and `true` already occupied for *Parse successful* result reporting). It is inherent for recursive descending parsers implementation in *C++*. But if we change result type of `parse` from `bool` to something more wide, we can distinct reporting hard or soft errors (or something else) during parse in more flexible way — by means of different values of return code.

Comment: Woot. You finally got me to try X3. I like it a lot

Comment: I know it is wrong to ask two questions into one. For second part of question I found the answer: I use *libunwind*, as it described in latest [Eli Bendersky's article](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/programmatic-access-to-the-call-stack-in-c/), and linking against it. It looks like there is interference between system-wide installed libunwind and *gdb*, which internally uses *libunwind* (likely of different version).

Comment: ok - interesting. Have that in the back of my mind now for future reference

Comment: @sehe Not worth. I can't reproduce the behaviour on another machines.

Comment: Okay, thanks for even that nudge. Stuff happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot avoid throwing the expectation failure when using the expectation parser. It's the purpose of this operator.

Use `operator>>` for "back-trackable expectations" (i.e. alternatives).

When you do use expectation points (`operator>`) just handle the exception too¹.

> **Note** This looks like a typo
>
> ```
> ('(' > -lvalue_list > '>')
> ```
>
> should probably be
>
> ```
> ('(' > -lvalue_list > ')')
> ```

Also `return one end` doesn't match `"begin" >> statements >> "end"` regardless of what `statements` is defined as...

Fixing things:

**[Live With Rule Debugging](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ab7de188dc272bd)** (c++14 only)

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

namespace SO {
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

    x3::symbols<char> const keyword = []{
        x3::symbols<char> kw;
        kw += "for","begin","end","function","while","break","switch";
        return kw;
    }();

    x3::rule<struct symbol_tag>      const symbol     ("symbol");
    x3::rule<struct identifier_tag>  const identifier ("identifier");
    x3::rule<struct lvalue_list_tag> const lvalue_list("lvalue_list");
    x3::rule<struct statements_tag>  const statements ("statements");
    x3::rule<struct rule_tag>        const rule       ("rule");

    auto symbol_def      = x3::lexeme[x3::alnum >> *(x3::alnum | '_')];
    auto identifier_def  = (!(x3::lexeme[keyword >> !(x3::alnum | '_')]) >> symbol);
    auto lvalue_list_def = identifier % ',';
    auto statements_def  = *identifier;
    auto rule_def        = "function"
                     >> identifier
                     >> ('(' > -lvalue_list > ')')
                     >> ("begin" > statements > "end")
                     ;

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(symbol, identifier, lvalue_list, statements, rule)
}

int main() {
    std::string const sample = "function a() begin return one end";
    auto f = sample.begin(), l = sample.end();

    bool ok = phrase_parse(f, l, SO::rule, SO::x3::space);
    if (ok)
        std::cout << "Parse success\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";

    if (f!=l)
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
<rule>
  <try>function a() begin r</try>
  <identifier>
    <try> a() begin return on</try>
    <symbol>
      <try> a() begin return on</try>
      <success>() begin return one </success>
    </symbol>
    <success>() begin return one </success>
  </identifier>
  <lvalue_list>
    <try>) begin return one e</try>
    <identifier>
      <try>) begin return one e</try>
      <symbol>
        <try>) begin return one e</try>
        <fail/>
      </symbol>
      <fail/>
    </identifier>
    <fail/>
  </lvalue_list>
  <statements>
    <try> return one end</try>
    <identifier>
      <try> return one end</try>
      <symbol>
        <try> return one end</try>
        <success> one end</success>
      </symbol>
      <success> one end</success>
    </identifier>
    <identifier>
      <try> one end</try>
      <symbol>
        <try> one end</try>
        <success> end</success>
      </symbol>
      <success> end</success>
    </identifier>
    <identifier>
      <try> end</try>
      <fail/>
    </identifier>
    <success> end</success>
  </statements>
  <success></success>
</rule>
Parse success
```

### Without Debug

It gets a lot simpler:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c07c14085ebc6d90)</kbd>** (g++/clang++)

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

    x3::symbols<char> keyword;
    keyword += "for","begin","end","function","while","break","switch";

    static auto symbol      = x3::lexeme[x3::alnum >> *(x3::alnum | '_')];
    static auto identifier  = (!(x3::lexeme[keyword >> !(x3::alnum | '_')]) >> symbol);
    static auto lvalue_list = identifier % ',';
    static auto statements  = *identifier;
    static auto rule        = "function"
                            >> identifier
                            >> ('(' > -lvalue_list > ')')
                            >> ("begin" > statements > "end")
                            ;

    std::string const sample = "function a() begin return one end";
    auto f = sample.begin(), l = sample.end();

    bool ok = phrase_parse(f, l, rule, x3::space);
    if (ok)
        std::cout << "Parse success\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";

    if (f!=l)
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
}
```

Just prints

```
Parse success
```

---

¹ And just to show you **can** handle the expectation failure just fine: [Expectation Failure Handling](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6461f997d4b1c8b)

Comment: And just to show you **can** handle the expectation failure just fine: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6461f997d4b1c8b

Comment: Yes, there was just a typo.

Comment: Can you say are there any obstacles to change result type of `parse` member functions of parser to return not just only `bool` as I mentioned above? In such a case one can avoid using an exception to handle hard errors.

Comment: Can you wrap it in a function that returns `optional<T>` or `maybe<T>` (assuming you bring your own `maybe` implementation)

Comment: the debug-version no longer compiles (I did "Edit", edited nothing, and then "Compile, link and run" on Coliru and I got an error "error: use of undeclared identifier 'symbol_def'").

Comment: @TemplateRex which link?

Comment: @TemplateRex Fixed. I don't know what the original syntax is derived from; this answer stems from before my learning X3 (see comment at OP's post :)). All I know is the `BOOST_SPIRIT_*` x3 macros assume a naming convention, and if you wish to deviate from that I'd probably write some of the plumbing manually (the plumbing is there to map parser types to their tags and definitions).

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently learning X3 to get a PGN parser for draughts/checkers to work. It's not been the smoothest of experiences so far, but copying from your answers here and there certainly helps :)