# Combining rules at runtime and returning rules

Tags: c++, c++14, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

I am trying to write some complex parser made on top of Spirit-X3, so I need to know some things:

♦ How to combine rules at runtime. (with Nabialek's trick)

♦ Is it ok to return rules like this:

```
x3::rule<char> SomeFunction(std::string &str)
{
    x3::rule<char> foo;
    auto bar = baz;
    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(foo, bar);
    return foo;
}
```

PS: SomeFunction won't have a fixed return, so I can't use just a x3::sequence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, x3 makes it a lot easier to compose rules.

Mainly because parser expressions don't have the tendency to keep references to temporaries when assigned to variables, like they used to in the age of Qi¹.

Limitation: declaring parsers with external linkage is a lot more ... complicated in X3, requiring the dance with the macros that you show `BOOST_SPIRIT_{DECLARE,DEFINE}`.

### Your Sample

That won't fly because the macro is meant to be used at namespace scope. The good news is you may not need it, because there is no need to declare the rule separately from the definition unless you are dealing with recursively required rules.

As an aside `x3::rule<char>` is likely a mistake. `char` is a *tag type* in that declaration, and that's not a good tag type. If you wanted an *attribute* type instead, that needs to be the second template argument.

```
auto SomeFunction(std::string &str)
{
    return x3::rule<struct _tag, std::string> {"dynamic"}
        = '[' >> x3::lit(str) >> ']';
}
```

In fact I very frequently make little factories at my declaration site:

```
template <typename Attr>
auto compose = [](auto p1, auto p2) {
     return rule<struct _, Attr> {"compose"}
         = nocase [ 
               lexeme [ "property:" << as_parser(p1) ]
               >> '='
               lexeme [ "value:" << as_parser(p2) ]
           ];                  
};
```

That's a bit contrived but should give you ideas. Use it like `compose<int>("number", x3::int_)` or `compose<std::string>("name", +x3::graph)`

### Some Inspirational Examples

- [Understanding the List Operator (%) in Boost.Spirit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33816662/understanding-the-list-operator-in-boost-spirit/33817135#33817135) showing an ad-hoc `as<>[]` facility:

  ```
  namespace {
      template <typename T>
      struct as_type {
          template <typename Expr>
              auto operator[](Expr&& expr) const {
                  return x3::rule<struct _, T>{"as"} = x3::as_parser(std::forward<Expr>(expr));
              }
      };

      template <typename T> static const as_type<T> as = {};
  }
  ```
- [Avoid throwing expectation_failure when expectation parser fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31553900/avoid-throwing-expectation-failure-when-expectation-parser-fails/31563218#31563218) which dynamically composes a symbols lookup:

  ```
  x3::symbols<char> const keyword = []{
      x3::symbols<char> kw;
      kw += "for","begin","end","function","while","break","switch";
      return kw;
  }();
  ```
- [Dynamically switching symbol tables in x3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49246414/dynamically-switching-symbol-tables-in-x3/49269239#49269239) which is a **very** complete example with many parser factories:

  ```
  // (case insensitive) keyword handling
  static auto kw        = [](auto p) { return x3::lexeme[p >> !(x3::graph - x3::char_("/=,()"))]; };
  static auto ikw       = [](auto p) { return x3::no_case [kw(p)]; };
  static auto qualifier = [](auto p) { return x3::lexeme['/' >> ikw(p)]; };
  ```

  And even shows how to override `as_spirit_parser` for your own types:

  ```
  // Options and CiOptions
  namespace util {
      template <typename Tag>
      auto as_spirit_parser(Options<Tag> const& o, bool to_lower = false) {
          x3::symbols<typename Options<Tag>::type> p;
          int n = 0;
          for (std::string el : o._options) {
              if (to_lower) boost::to_lower(el);
              p.add(el, n++);
          }
          return kw(p);
      }

      template <typename Tag>
      auto as_spirit_parser(IcOptions<Tag> const& o) {
          return x3::no_case [ as_spirit_parser(o, true) ];
      }
  }
  ```

  And pretty elegant way to write member-wise propagation helpers with auto-generated semantic actions:

  ```
      auto set = [](auto member, auto p) {
          auto propagate = [member](auto& ctx) {
              traits::move_to(_attr(ctx), _val(ctx).*(member));
          };
          return as_parser(p)[propagate];
      };

      using T = ast::ShowSymbolsCommand;;
      return qualifier("all")  >> set(&T::all, attr(true))
           | qualifier("full") >> set(&T::full, attr(true))
           | qualifier("out")  >> set(&T::out, '=' >> Filespec)
           | qualifier("type") >> set(&T::types, '=' >> SymbolTypes)
           | set(&T::wildcard, Wildcard);
  ```

I strongly suggest you per-use these examples to get a sense of just how powerful X3 composing is. Only when you /really/ require it would I consider recreating something like `qi::lazy` in X3

---

¹ or in fact anything Proto-based, like Phoenix too

Comment: Linked "Some Inspirational Examples" that should give you a good sense of how you can compose parsers in X3

Comment: Just remembered that writing custom parsers is _also_ a lot simpler in x3. [Here are 3 posts containing examples of that](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371+x3+parser_base)